# Uploading a file from internal storage to a website

Tags: android, file-io, internal-storage

I've got an app running on a Nexus 7 that has no external storage (no SD card).  This app saves data to a .txt file.  I am trying to upload this file to a website which will then process the data.  The problem is that I cannot select files to upload seemingly because all files on the device are internal storage.

So my question:  Is there any way to change permissions on an internal storage file?  If not, is there any way I can alter my app (java) to save the file in such a way that it can be uploaded in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

If only this third-party app saves file with [Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) flag, you can read this file from your app and upload it. (as well as [Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE), this flag is deprecated since api 17). Another way to access any file from internal storage on rooted device using DDMS is described on [CommonsBlog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

If you save file to internal storage from your own app, you have complete freedom to read and upload it anywhere. To allow other apps on device to access this file, use Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE while saving file, or better use ContentProvider to share file to other apps.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I ended up resolving the whole thing by downloading a better file manager app.  There are several out there that work, but some of them are not accessible via a browser.  I found that ES File Explorer works just fine for this task.